# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes

Tags: android, android-activity

I try selecting a subsettings in the settings app of my device, and i see this exception. Does this mean settings is a privileged process and can't access webview?

I tried selecting HDMI option from settings, this is the exception stack:

```
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:96)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2194)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2189)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2248)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3588)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3682)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:544)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:489)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:472)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:459)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:449)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at com.android.settings.HDMI3DPlaySettings.onCreate(HDMI3DPlaySettings.java:123)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:483)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.switchToFragment(SettingsActivity.java:1002)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:599)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
03-23 08:45:03.301 E/AndroidRuntime( 3299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
```

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` on your manifest?

Comment: Yes..the exception is present here in android source code:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewFactory.java                                                final int uid = android.os.Process.myUid();
            if (uid == android.os.Process.ROOT_UID || uid == android.os.Process.SYSTEM_UID) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        "For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes");

Comment: yes the permission is present in the app.

Comment: Then show us your code, to see what are you doing wrong.

Comment: Added the exception stack, it tries to create a webview object for HDMI, causing exception, preventing creation of webview object for a privileged process.

Comment: the line that causes error is simply this: mWebView = new WebView(activity), //mWebView is WebView object to display HDMI help information., so error occurs in webview<init> as you can see from exception stack too.

Comment: In case of rooted phones, you can try `adb shell setenforce permissive` for android versions 5.1 and below. FOr 6.0 and above follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/42581992/4269615

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met the same case;
Added [android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"] in manifest, and used the webview in APP;
It was all right in android 5.0.2 project, while failed in 5.1 project...

Comment: I learnt that Using webview in a system app compromises the security of the system, so if possible we can find alternatives to using webview.

Comment: Did you find an alternative solution? Thank you.

Comment: It's not working in 6.0.1 again, have you found any alternative? If so, please comment the same.

Comment: mine is targeting to 8.1 Oreo version. Have got "UnsupportedOperationException". I think it didn't supports from 5.1 version, kindly suggest any other possibilities to fix

Answer (score 14):

```
public static void hookWebView() {
    int sdkInt = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    try {
        Class<?> factoryClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewFactory");
        Field field = factoryClass.getDeclaredField("sProviderInstance");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object sProviderInstance = field.get(null);
        if (sProviderInstance != null) {
            log.debug("sProviderInstance isn't null");
            return;
        }
        Method getProviderClassMethod;
        if (sdkInt > 22) { // above 22
            getProviderClassMethod = factoryClass.getDeclaredMethod("getProviderClass");
        } else if (sdkInt == 22) { // method name is a little different
            getProviderClassMethod = factoryClass.getDeclaredMethod("getFactoryClass");
        } else { // no security check below 22
            log.info("Don't need to Hook WebView");
            return;
        }
        getProviderClassMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> providerClass = (Class<?>) getProviderClassMethod.invoke(factoryClass);
        Class<?> delegateClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewDelegate");
        Constructor<?> providerConstructor = providerClass.getConstructor(delegateClass);
        if (providerConstructor != null) {
            providerConstructor.setAccessible(true);
            Constructor<?> declaredConstructor = delegateClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
            declaredConstructor.setAccessible(true);
            sProviderInstance = providerConstructor.newInstance(declaredConstructor.newInstance());
            log.debug("sProviderInstance:{}", sProviderInstance);
            field.set("sProviderInstance", sProviderInstance);
        }
        log.debug("Hook done!");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

Run this method before creating WebView.

Android do such security check during creating `WebViewFactory`'s field `sProviderInstance`(when it is null), and `sProviderInstance` is a static field. So we can make a instance of `sProviderInstance` before the security check by using reflection.

See android 5.1 source code below.

```
static WebViewFactoryProvider getProvider() {
    synchronized (sProviderLock) {
        // For now the main purpose of this function (and the factory abstraction) is to keep
        // us honest and minimize usage of WebView internals when binding the proxy.
        if (sProviderInstance != null) return sProviderInstance;

        final int uid = android.os.Process.myUid();
        if (uid == android.os.Process.ROOT_UID || uid == android.os.Process.SYSTEM_UID) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in 
privileged processes");
        }

...
```

Comment: Works for me too! (With Xamarin) Thanks a lot.

Comment: fail on Android 8.1

Comment: not work on android 8.1

Comment: Work on android 7.  great

Answer (score 0):

This exception is generated by WebViewFactory, here is the code:

```
 final int uid = android.os.Process.myUid();
        if (uid == android.os.Process.ROOT_UID || uid == android.os.Process.SYSTEM_UID
                || uid == android.os.Process.PHONE_UID || uid == android.os.Process.NFC_UID
                || uid == android.os.Process.BLUETOOTH_UID) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes");
        }
```

so, if you will try to use web view with mentioned UID usage, the app will crash.

I also need to use webView to show html in my app, but can not find some standard solution.

Comment: try to use some library as this one: 
https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview

Answer (score 0):

same of [Zhenghong Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043138/zhenghong-wang)'s answer, but it works on android 8.1

```
public static void hookWebView() {
        int sdkInt = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        try {
            Class<?> factoryClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewFactory");
            Field field = factoryClass.getDeclaredField("sProviderInstance");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object sProviderInstance = field.get(null);
            if (sProviderInstance != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sProviderInstance isn't null");
                return;
            }
            Method getProviderClassMethod;
            if (sdkInt > 22) { // above 22
                getProviderClassMethod = factoryClass.getDeclaredMethod("getProviderClass");
            } else if (sdkInt == 22) { // method name is a little different
                getProviderClassMethod = factoryClass.getDeclaredMethod("getFactoryClass");
            } else { // no security check below 22
                Log.i(TAG, "Don't need to Hook WebView");
                return;
            }
            getProviderClassMethod.setAccessible(true);
            Class<?> providerClass = (Class<?>) getProviderClassMethod.invoke(factoryClass);
            Class<?> delegateClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewDelegate");
            Constructor<?> declaredConstructor = delegateClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
            declaredConstructor.setAccessible(true);
            sProviderInstance = providerClass
                    .getDeclaredMethod("create", delegateClass)
                    .invoke(providerClass, declaredConstructor.newInstance());
            Log.d("sProviderInstance", sProviderInstance.toString());
            field.set("sProviderInstance", sProviderInstance);
            Log.d(TAG, "Hook done!");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "hook WebView Failed", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this work on 8.1, but isn't the same as wbview.  this code start webview as browser with tabs

Comment: sProviderInstance = providerClass
                    .getDeclaredMethod("create", delegateClass)
                    .invoke(providerClass, declaredConstructor.newInstance())

Crashes on this line because there's no such method named as create. Downvoting

Comment: maybe there is a little bit difference between the default webview of the OS. I debug and test this code on android AOSP 8.1, like Zhenghong Wang's answer, the main purpose is to create a sProviderInstance before the security check. since the constructor of sProviderInstance is missing on android 8.1, and I found that there is a method create under that class during debugging. So you may need some debug works. hope it helps.