# UnsupportedOperationException: WebView is not allowed in privileged processes

Tags: java, android, webview

I am using `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in my manifest to obtain some unavoidable rights.  (to read HDMI input from an [Android box](http://eweat.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008848465509/pdtl/HD-set-top/1143517456/TV-Box-R9-Mini.htm))

My app also uses a `webview` to serve an important function. **But the combination of using `webView` and `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` is causing the following exception (API level 23, rooted device, system app)**:

Caused by: **`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes`**

1. Please suggest a solution to use both in combination.
2. What are those security reasons?

Full stack trace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.blynq.app.fragments.PlayerPane.onCreateView(PlayerPane.java:200)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5453)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.blynq.app.fragments.PlayerPane.onCreateView(PlayerPane.java:200) 
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5453) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.blynq.app.fragments.PlayerPane.onCreateView(PlayerPane.java:200) 
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5453) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes
    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:159)
    at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2277)
    at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2272)
    at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2331)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3795)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3898)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
    at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:597)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.blynq.app.fragments.PlayerPane.onCreateView(PlayerPane.java:200) 
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5453) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` and install app as system app

Follow this procedure to install app as system app:

1. Root the android device
2. Connect to device using `adb connect IP:5555`
3. Install the app as user app (You can use `adb install app_name.apk`)
4. `adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system`
5. `adb shell mv /data/app/<package_name>-1 /system/app/` (Moves app resources from /data directory to /system directory)
6. Reboot the Android device