# WebView is not working in Android 13 system App

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

I am using web view to load URLs in my application. but since my app is system application it's not working. When I try after removing ' android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" ' this tag from manifest URLs are loading. I am using Android 13 device. What is the reason for this problem and how to resolve this?

I tried in Android 12 also same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your device is rooted.

Have you already tried this StackOverflow solution?

[Accepted solution for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581992/19386155)