# For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes

Tags: android, react-native

We are using React Native to build an app of WebRTC. When we change it to a system app, it crashes with this error message:

```
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.daxiaoipc, PID: 7273
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:236)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:47)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:136)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:53)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.kt:47)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer.loadForRequest(ReactCookieJarContainer.java:44)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:74)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
03-28 15:39:13.467  7273  7613 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Here are some points:

1. The error message is `For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes`.
2. There is `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in AndroidManifest.xml.
3. We didn't use `WebView` in out project.
4. We use `react-native` and `react-native-webrtc` on Android 10.
5. The crash is caused by a `fetch` call. `fetch` invokes `okhttp3` and `okhttp3` invokes `webkit`, then invokes `webview`. We can see the invocation chain from the call stack above.
6. It works when we change it back to a normal app.

Our question is: How could we do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

We resolve it by hooking the `webview` according to [this pose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228183/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-for-security-reasons-webview-is-not-al). It seems that React Native depends on `webview`. Since we are going to use React Native to develop system apps, we hope that Facebook would remove the dependency on `webview` in the future.